# Actionbar with custom layout show me icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a actionbar with a custom layout, but this show me the icon at right i set false the texttitle, description and uselogo.

Photo:

[image: a busy cat]

This is my code:

```
    // Gestion del ActionBar y contexto
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

This is the actionbar.xml, only have a image, 2 textview and other image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="Nº de Usuario: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="12sp" android:shadowColor="#232323" android:shadowDx="0" android:shadowDy="-1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvABCodigoUsuario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="12sp" android:shadowColor="#232323" android:shadowDx="0" android:shadowDy="-1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/header_logo" android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/header_bt_off" android:layout_marginRight="14dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:text="Nombre: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="12sp" android:layout_marginLeft="45dp" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" android:shadowColor="#232323" android:shadowDx="0" android:shadowDy="-1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use actionbar sherlock and 2.3

Comment: Please provide actionbar xml file..........

Comment: is this icon is in this xml ? as I have not the draw-able so can't detect ......looks as header_bt_off?

Comment: No, this icon is the app icon not be in XML

Comment: power button ( icon at right ) is  app icon?

Comment: No, powerbutton is the rigth image, i want to hide the left icon, usually i use         actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
but this dont work

Comment: can you check the availablity of  ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); in supported library ..

Comment: actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
Exists, but show the icon.

Comment: sorry can you try one last setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) ..

Comment: Yes, ab.setdisplayhomeenabled(false) hide the icon! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` to hide the icon.